# Python GCD - errors

Tags: python, fractions, greatest-common-divisor

I have an issue with my code whose purpose is to find the GCD of two inputs. When I try to run the module it tells me that 'gcd' is not defined.

```
def GCD(12,4):
    gcd = 1
    for i in range(2, max(12,4)/2):
        if((12 % i == 0) and (4 % i == 0)):
            gcd = i
    return gcd
```

Comment: Just so you know, Python comes with the Fractions module. Includes a [gcd method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the `GCF` function. You have just defined your function. You need to add a line

```
gcf = GCF(a,b)
```

after the place where you accept the input. That is after  `b = int(input('denomenator: '))`

Edit:

Change the input statements to

```
a = float(input('numerator: '))
b = float(input('denomenator: '))
```

Comment: Ok I did that but now it says "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Euclid division algorithm** to find gcd in less time.
Take floating point numbers to a and b.

```
def gcd(a,b):
    c = 1
    a,b = max(a,b),min(a,b)
    while c != 0:
        c = a%b
        a,b = b,c
    return a
print gcd(12,5)
```